How to define QNetworkRequest object from cpp to qml
I have made a frontend piece of registration page in QML and processing of textInput using the setContextProperty function. But I have a problem when I need to do post request. Responsible for this method
void NetworkManager::sendRequest(const QNetworkRequest &request, const QJsonObject &data) {
    QNetworkReply *reply = m_manager->post(request, QJsonDocument(data).toJson());
    m_replies.append(reply);
}

m_manager and m_replies defined in class so
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *m_manager;
    QList<QNetworkReply *> m_replies;

I tried to use method sendRequest inside onClicked signal on reg button. But if I trying to define QNetworkRequest object in QML I have an error:
no matching function for call to
'QQmlContext::setContextProperty(const char[15], QNetworkRequest&)'
I have read the documentation of QQmlContext and QVariant, and I understood, that I can't to define QNetworkRequest object in this way. I tried  to define a button from QML to C++ with objectName and use signals and slots but it isn't working to. Maybe someone knows any methods to define C++ objects in QML, or QML to C++? I haven't found it yet.

This may be off topic, but there is an XMLHttpRequest that can be defined and used in QML without using C++ at all.

Well, I don't have any ideas, how to define a QNetworkRequest object from cpp to qml. Because of this I have made several identical methods, with hardcode URL inside and query items


void NetworkManager::sendAuthRequest(QString authPhone){
    QUrl url("http://89.221.60.161:3000/api/auth/login");

    QUrlQuery query;
    QByteArray postData;
    query.addQueryItem("phone", authPhone);
    query.addQueryItem("notificationToken", "d3ef6dac-38b5-442e-898b-b030d014efb9");

    postData = query.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8();

    QNetworkRequest request(url);
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    m_manager->post(request, postData);

};



the function parameters are passed from qml, where I have defined the parameters in advance


    onClicked:{
        var authPhone = inputNumber.text
        manager.sendAuthRequest(authPhone);
    }



I don't like this solution, but maybe it will help someone, or someone will come up with a better solution.

I have found a solution to my problem:
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("UserRegRequest", QVariant::fromValue(UserRegRequest));

Create QML object from C++ with specified properties

Once you find a solution, we don't close the question, but leave it open so future visitors will be able to find your question and its answers. Plus, other users may leave more answers if better/different solutions are found. Instead, you can click the checkmark on your answer so it turns green, signaling to future users that said answer is the one that solved your problem.

I understood, that it isn't a solution, because i get an error: server replied: Bad Request. But if i doing hardcode url inside sendRequest method everything works. It means that if i need to do post request for multiple pages, i need to make several similar methods sendRequest with hardcode url inside sendRequest methods.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
